# How to use TIdWhois with SOCKS proxy

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm getting whois information using this code:

```
IdWhois1.Host := 'whois.nic.tld';
ServerResultStr := IdWhois1.WhoIs('google.tld');
```

But I need to query the whois server (port 43) using a SOCKS proxy server.

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3. Is there any way to achieve this by using TIdWhois?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOCKS is handled in Indy using the `TIdSocksInfo` component.  You can configure it with the proxy details as needed (Host, Port, Version, Authentication, etc).

To make `TIdWhois` (or any TCP client) connect to its target server through `TIdSocksInfo`, you need to do the following:

- assign a `TIdIOHandlerSocket`-derived component (`TIdIOHandlerStack`, or any `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived component, like `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`) to the `TIdWhois.IOHandler` property.
- assign the `TIdSocksInfo` to the `IOHandler`'s `TransparentProxy` property.